# SAP HANA, query to check the size of the FullBackup as displayed in the HANA Studio backup catalog

Tags: hana, hana-sql-script, hana-studio

I need help in creating an SQL query that can retrieve the size occupied by the latest FullBackup in HANA Studio. I haven't been able to find this SQL query in any forum or SAP note. Any ideas on how to obtain this value?

Example :

```
SELECT TOP 1 STATE_NAME, BACKUP_SIZE 
FROM SYS.M_BACKUP_CATALOG 
WHERE entry_type_name = 'complete data backup' 
ORDER BY ENTRY_ID DESC;
```

Specifically, the value I want to obtain is the one shown in the following image:

[image: This value need]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a very product specific question, so I have remove the general ANSI/ISO <sql> tag.